# Why value of Double can't be converted to Any?

Tags: swift

With Xcode 9 GM (Swift 4), I see

**error: cannot convert value of type 'Double' to specified type 'Any?'**

for code:

```
var a: Any? = +30.0
```

Why?

Comment: Seems like a bug (regression from 3.1), present when applying the overloaded prefix `+` operator to a floating point literal. I believe there are at least two implicit conversions present here (which may lead to the compiler's confusion): a non-`Any` instance to `Any`, as well as a non-optional to an optional. In case you can't find an open bug report for this, you should probably considering filing one yourself. Peculiarly, using the `-` prefix operator on a floating point literal (in the use case as above) seems valid.

Comment: If you make your comment an answer, I would accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Since I'm only speculating and don't have the time to dig into Swift's source code atm, I'll just leave it as a comment, but again, posting a bug report at Swift's JIRA might be appropriate (and will probably give you a definite answer). If I were to take a guess, I believe that `Numeric` could be part of the culprint here, as I believe `Double`, `Float` and `Int` all fall back on  `Numeric`'s default implementation for the `+` prefix operator in the use case of numeric literals, whereas they have their own overloads of the `-` prefix operator. ...

Comment: ... This in combination with the implicit conversions might confuse the precedence choices for the compiler when inferring the type of `+1.0` in the implicit conversion context you show above. But this is just a guess.

Comment: Addendum: If you decide to post a bug report, you might want to mention/link it as related to [SR-3953](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3953), which I speculate is due to the same root issue (whereas the regression is possibly due to `Numeric`). When I look around at their JIRA, I can't find a bug report for this case, which probably isn't to surprising at it's a regression and also quite the corner case. Just giving the compiler a little help with its inference voids the error, e.g. `let a: Any? = .some(+30.0)` or, as mentioned below, `var a: Any? = Double(+30.0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` is causing confusion.

```
var a: Any? = 30.0
```

works.

Or you can create a `Double` and assign that:

```
var a: Any? = Double(+30.0)
```

Comment: Using a "+" makes the logic obvious in the context. Curious why I need to get rid of it. Thank you all the same.

Comment: Since this answer covers workarounds (for the bug?), for completeness, another alternative to using the literal expression to explicitly construct a non-optional `Double`, would be using the literal expression to construct an `Optional`, however in that case not needing to specify it's wrapped type: `let a: Any? = .some(+30.0)`. Both remove a layer of implicit conversions, where these conversions are probably strongly related to the compiler's failure to infer type and perform the assignment (as e.g. `let a: Any = +30.0` also works, which also removes one of the implicit conversions).